# C# mvc how to start with an index file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-hosting

I have a project that I want to deploy on a host, but I got this error message:

No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.htm,index.shtml,index.php,index.php5,index.php4,index.php3,index.phtml,index.cgi) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

It's running on shared host linux servers.

What do I have to do to make my application to work again?

Comment: Did you have it working on that how *before*?

Comment: How do you expect to get a C# MVC app to work on a Linux server?

Comment: You are trying to host a C# MVC application on Apache. This isn't supported OOTB (and the support that exists is patchy). By being on share hosting (having no control of the server), there's not really a way you can fix this. You need to have a dedicated server, preferably running Windows and IIS, or alternatively Mono which doesn't support *everything* and will likely require some changes to your application. Alternatively, you could re-engineer your application in PHP or another language supported by your host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MVC 4 you cannot host it on Linux. Microsoft did release .NET Core as open source this year and next MVC vNext will allow hosting on linux using MONO framework.

You can read more and play with it:
http://graemechristie.github.io/graemechristie/blog/2014/05/26/asp-dot-net-vnext-on-osx-and-linux/

Many more articles are online.